# How to tell what type of RFID tag?

Tags: rfid, nfc, tag, hf

I have an RFID tag for access to my apartment building that I would like to clone(buying one through strata would be 100s of dollars).

I have a proxmark 3 easy and have cloned tags in the past with great success. However the proxmark cant even see that its there on either HF or LF. So im assuming its a UHF tag.

Is there a way to tell what type of tag it is without pulling it apart?
Is there another device or attachment I can use to read and clone this tag?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there probably is another device or attachment that could be used

Comment: Some useful additional information for identifying the RFID type could be: appearance, range, influence of metal shielding / liquids on the range.

Comment: start by measuring the frequency used by the reader,